# Configuring logstash for multiple input (port and log file path)

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I've Configured three of my network devices to write their logs in separated file in /var/log and also i configured my Logstash to read these file as input and it's working well and i could create index for them and i configured my cisco device to send its log in netflow format and i've installed netflow plugin for it and it started to work well but i figure out that my other index that was reading their input from /var/log stop working but as soon as is comment modules part in logsatsh.yml :
#modules:

- name: netflow
  var.input.udp.port: 2055

my other index start working again but my netflow index stop working and i don't know how to configure logstash to use path file and port as input at the same time. would you please help me in this case.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into pipelines.yml and create a second pipeline config folder, seperating input, filter and output, so that they will not break eachother.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html